# Temporarily disable notifications

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, app-widgets, silent-mode

I need a way to temporarily disable all notifications with ONE CLICK ONLY, for example via widget or EQS.
I don't care if it is for all apps or just whatsapp, as long as it prevents vibration and especially the notification light.
Is there any way to do this?

On Rooted Android 4.4.2, HTC Desire 816 dual sim

Comment: There is in Android lollipop.

Comment: What kind of phone?  What OS?  Rooted or not?  A little more information would surely help!

Comment: Their is an app over the [Google PlayStore with the name Notification off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff&hl=en) which you can use to turn all the notifications down at a single tap but it's going to need rooted permission to work correct. So, you can try using that and if that's something which isn't possible then you can always use the Silent mode over your device !

Comment: Updated info.

Notification off seems like the right thing, but it isn't really one click. you need to go into the app each time and click more than once, both to enable it or to disable it

Comment: Answered at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32229/temporarily-disable-popups-on-android-facebook-snapchat-line-etc (with one-click widget)